# Stopping screen command from PHP doesn't stop actual process

Tags: php, debian, daemon, freebsd, gnu-screen

The following scheme works like a charm in my vagrantbox under Debian, but doesn't work properly at production under FreeBSD.

1) I execute my symfony command via the console: `php my:command start`. It runs `my:daemon` command from inside, wrapped into screen like this: `cd ~/path && screen -dmS mydaemon php bin/console my:daemon`, and it works good.

2) When that command started it executes another 3 commands in screen like `screen -dmS myworkerX php bin/console my:worker --id=X` and this also works good.

For your understanding, how it looks in process tree:

```
 - screen -dmS mydaemon php bin/console my:daemon
   - php bin/console my:daemon
     - screen -dmS myworker1 php bin/console my:worker --id=1
         - php bin/console my:worker --id=1
     - screen -dmS myworker2 php bin/console my:worker --id=2
         - php bin/console my:worker --id=2
     - screen -dmS myworker3 php bin/console my:worker --id=3
         - php bin/console my:worker --id=3
```

Result of screen command is shown below:

```
$ screen -list
There are screens on:
    16362.mydaemon  (Detached)
    16372.myworker1 (Detached)
    16378.myworker2 (Detached)
    16384.myworker3 (Detached)
```

At this point, all works fine both on freebsd and debian. The problem is in my stop script. I run `php bin/console my:daemon stop`, and it calls `screen -S screenName -X quit` command for each of all screen IDs used: mydaemon, myworker1, myworker2, myworker3. Usually, when wrapping screen process stops, it kills the actual process running inside. Under debian it is true. And under FreeBSD it stops screen process, but leaving inner php process is untouched. So `screen -list` command shows empty list, but `ps aux | grep my:worker` says that all processes continue to work in background.

I'd like to ask, can anybody suppose where is the difference between behaviour of `screen` command on these operating systems?

Comment: don't use screen as a process supervisor I would suggest using something better like immortal  https://immortal.run/post/run.yml/

Comment: If you're not already, I'd try running `ps aux | grep my:worker` through `exec()` or whatever, within the actual Symfony command and dumping the output. Check it actually sees the processes.

I'm not sure if it'd affect screen the same way but I've ran into issues before where it wouldn't see/return any PIDs with `ps axf | grep mything.py` if my Artisan command was called from cron. Still not sure why!